# Working with Azure Event Grid and blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, webhooks, azure-eventgrid

I am new to Azure Event Grid and Webhooks.

How can I bind my .net mvc web api application to Microsoft Azure Event Grid?

In short I want, whenever a new file is added to blob storage, Azure Event grid should notify my web api application.

I tried following article but no luck 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-quickstart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I bind my .net mvc web api application to Microsoft Azure Event Grid?
>   In short I want, whenever a new file is added to blob storage, Azure Event grid should notify my web api application.

I do a demo for that, it works correctly on my side. You could refer to the following steps:

1.Create a demo RestAPI project just with function

```
 public string Post([FromBody] object value) //Post
 {
      return $"value:{value}";
 }
```

2.If we want to intergrate azure storage with Azure Event Grid, we need to create a [blob storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-create-storage-account) in location **West US2** or **West Central US**. More details could refer to the screen shot.

[image]

2.Create **Storage Accounts** type Event Subscriptions and bind the custom API endpoint

[image]

[image]

3.Upload the blob to the blob storage and check from the Rest API.

[image]

Comment: Great. It worked. I was trying to deploy it on EAST US location which is wrong. Thank you :)

Comment: I tested the entire thing with RequestBin tool and it worked as expected. But now when I try to change Full Endpoint URL with my web api url, azure is not accepting/saving changes. Do I need an https web api URL ? Right now I have http url

Comment: @Tom Sun, Did you check the same example with sample WEB API?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by creating an custom endpoint that will subscribe to the events published from Event Grid. The documentation you referenced uses Request Bin as a subscriber. Instead create a Web API endpoint in your MVC application to receive the notification. You'll have to support the validation request just to make you have a valid subscriber and then you are off and running.

Example:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Request.Headers["aeg-event-type"].FirstOrDefault() == "SubscriptionValidation")
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                var validationRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GridEvent[]>(result);
                var validationCode = validationRequest[0].Data["validationCode"];

                var validationResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {validationResponse = validationCode});
                return new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, 
                    Content = new StringContent(validationResponse)
                };                       
            }
        }

        // Handle normal blob event here

        return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
    }
```

Comment: Hi, How can we check and send this validation code in WEB API?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an up-to-date sample of how you would handle it with a Web API. You can also review and deploy a working sample from here: https://github.com/dbarkol/azure-event-grid-viewer

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            var jsonContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            // Check the event type.
            // Return the validation code if it's 
            // a subscription validation request. 
            if (EventTypeSubcriptionValidation)
            {
                var gridEvent =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GridEvent<Dictionary<string, string>>>>(jsonContent)
                        .First();


                // Retrieve the validation code and echo back.
                var validationCode = gridEvent.Data["validationCode"];
                return new JsonResult(new{ 
                    validationResponse = validationCode
                });
            }
            else if (EventTypeNotification)
            {
                // Do more here...
                return Ok();                 
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

    }

public class GridEvent<T> where T: class
{
    public string Id { get; set;}
    public string EventType { get; set;}
    public string Subject {get; set;}
    public DateTime EventTime { get; set; } 
    public T Data { get; set; } 
    public string Topic { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid nuget package.

From the following article (credit to gldraphael): https://gldraphael.com/blog/creating-an-azure-eventgrid-webhook-in-asp-net-core/

```
[Route("/api/webhooks"), AllowAnonymous]
public class WebhooksController : Controller
{
    // POST: /api/webhooks/handle_ams_jobchanged
    [HttpPost("handle_ams_jobchanged")] // <-- Must be an HTTP POST action
    public IActionResult ProcessAMSEvent(
        [FromBody]EventGridEvent[] ev, // 1. Bind the request
        [FromServices]ILogger<WebhooksController> logger)
    {
        var amsEvent = ev.FirstOrDefault(); // TODO: handle all of them!
        if(amsEvent == null) return BadRequest();

        // 2. Check the eventType field
        if (amsEvent.EventType == EventTypes.MediaJobStateChangeEvent)
        {
            // 3. Cast the data to the expected type
            var data = (amsEvent.Data as JObject).ToObject<MediaJobStateChangeEventData>();

            // TODO: do your thing; eg:
            logger.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented));
        }

        // 4. Respond with a SubscriptionValidationResponse to complete the 
        // event subscription handshake.
        if(amsEvent.EventType == EventTypes.EventGridSubscriptionValidationEvent)
        {
            var data = (amsEvent.Data as JObject).ToObject<SubscriptionValidationEventData>();
            var response = new SubscriptionValidationResponse(data.ValidationCode);
            return Ok(response);
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```